# How to Display Only Parent Category in Post Url Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm New to WordPress and building an Multiple Choice Question Database Website. As you can see the post URL in Quite Long and Causing SEO Problems. I want to trim this url by only showing the parent category and post title in the link (i.e mcqs). I'm using a Hierarchical style categories.

MCQS (Parent)
-10th Class MCQS (Child)
--10th Class Chemistry MCQS (Child)

**CURRENT URL** http://fgstudy.com/mcqs/10th-class-mcqs/10th-class-chemistry-mcqs/10th-class-chemistry-mcqs-water

**URL I NEED** http://fgstudy.com/mcqs/10th-class-chemistry-mcqs-water/

Comment: You are able to do it by Redirection plugin. set redirection form source URL '/mcqs/10th-class-mcqs/10th-class-chemistry-mcqs/' and  target URL is '/mcqs/'

Comment: I have a lot of pages like this with different categories. Redirect cause problem to search engine indexing and also slow down website speed. I need something like regenerate all urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply Edit Post and Select MCQS (Category You Like) as the PRIMARY CATEGORY Update Post and DONE.
[View Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZck7.png)